# How to Set WebGLRender background to transparent

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, three.js

I'm trying to put objects in front of CSS3DObjects with the THREE.NoBlending hack. But I only see the black plane without the CSS3DObject in the newest revisions (tried r65 and r66). A small example I made looks like this:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="lib/three58.js"></script>
<script src="lib/CSS3dRenderer.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 555);
    camera.position.z += 20;

    var rendererCSS = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    rendererCSS.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    rendererCSS.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(rendererCSS.domElement);

    var rendererMain = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    rendererMain.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    rendererMain.setClearColor("white", 0);
    rendererMain.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.body.appendChild(rendererMain.domElement);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var sceneCSS = new THREE.Scene();

    var planeWidth = 15;
    var planeHeight = 15;

    var planeMaterial   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        blending: THREE.NoBlending,
        opacity : 0.0,
        transparent : true,
        color : 0x000000,
        side : THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight);
    var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    scene.add(planeMesh);

    var element = document.createElement('iframe')
    var aspectRatio = planeHeight / planeWidth;
    var elementWidth = 1024;
    var elementHeight = elementWidth * aspectRatio;
    element.src = 'moo.html';
    element.style.width = elementWidth + "px";
    element.style.height = elementHeight + "px";

    var objectCSS = new THREE.CSS3DObject(element);
    objectCSS.scale.x = planeWidth / elementWidth;
    objectCSS.scale.y = planeHeight / elementHeight;
    objectCSS.position = planeMesh.position;
    objectCSS.rotation = planeMesh.rotation;
    sceneCSS.add(objectCSS);

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5.0, 20.0, 20.0), material);
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(5.0, 20.0, 20.0), material);
    mesh.position.set(5, 0, -1); 
    mesh2.position.set(-8, 0, -6); 
    scene.add(mesh); // in front
    scene.add(mesh2); // behind

    animate();

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        rendererMain.render(scene, camera);
        rendererCSS.render(sceneCSS, camera);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

moo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color: purple">
<p align="center"><font color="lime" size="150">hello world</font> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

Revision 58: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAKsU.jpg

Revision 66: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzcSA.jpg

I've tried to understand why, it's probably something very simple. I can't find anything in migration that would change the behavior in this way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the "hack" supposed to do? Why do you have two planes in the same location? What is the z-index of the two renderer domElements supposed to be? What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @WestLangley The planeMesh with THREE.NoBlending helps me getting the CSS3DObject a sense of z-value in the world so I can put objects on top of it. So my question is why the CSS3DObject doesn't get rendered in the same way in the new revisions? It works good in revision 58 as you can see.

Comment: in this example the rendererMain gets added later so it's the same as putting z-index 1 on it. The rendererCSS is in the background but isn't seen through my transparent planeMesh "window", only in r58. Which is what I wonder why.

Comment: Try `rendererMain = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } )` and remove your so-called NoBlending hack.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a bunch! Makes sense too. Reason I called it a hack is because it doesn't feel completely obvious how to bake css into your 3d environment, thought it was really cool when I found out it was possible. I removed the "transparent: true" from the planeMesh too and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a transparent background with `WebGLRenderer`, you need to set `alpha = true` in the `WebGLRenderer` constructor. You can then set the clear color.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );

renderer.setClearColor( 0x00ff00, 0.5 );
```

three.js r.66