# Trying to add instructions to function in another class (es6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working on a project with video.js to display a video and a 3D render of a webpage.

I have already got a function that call the WebGL renderer but this function is defined in another plugin that I don't want to modify.

Function for WebGL renderer (this plugin has no errors for sure):

```js
var Canvas = function (baseComponent, THREE, settings = {}) {
    var parent = BaseCanvas(baseComponent, THREE, settings);

    return Util.extend(parent, {
    ...
      render: function(){
                  parent.render.call(this);
                  this.camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.cos( this.theta );
                  this.camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( this.phi );
                  this.camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( this.phi ) * Math.sin( this.theta );
                  this.camera.lookAt( this.camera.target );

                  if(!this.VRMode){
                      this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
                  }
              }
    ...
    }
}
```

So I've created another plugin to create the CSS3D renderer and my problem is: I want to call the render function for webgl and add my new render function of CSS3D. I did it like this:

```js
class css3d {
...

render(){
    this.canvas.render.bind(this);
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.canvas.camera)
  }
...
}
```

I've got no errors but my css renderer is not working. And I've already look for topic like this: [three.js properly blending css3d and webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681170/three-js-properly-blending-css3d-and-webgl) or topic like this: https://gist.github.com/leefsmp/38926bf2c379f604f9b5 but still not working.

Somebody could help me?

Comment: What do you mean when you say _"but my css renderer is not working"_? It's not being called? It's being called but not doing what you want? It's being called, but the original `render()` code is not being called? Have you put in any break points and stepped through the invocation of a call, to see if it's doing what you expect, and if the the `this` scope is what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both functions (render() with webgl and my function render() are called but I don't know how to put a breakpoint through the invocation of a call. This is the first time I need to use it. :/

Comment: See _[Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)_ or _[How to step through your code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code)_.

Comment: I used debugger in my function render and this is defined by my instance css3d this.canvas.render is also nice defined . All looks pretty good but the final result is not a 2000x2000px square with webpage (even if the page is loaded), it's two triangles face to face

Comment: You've done a good job of describing your problem and including your code, but you've failed to give us a way to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found my solution, I created a new frameanimation in my class. So now I've got a request animation frame for each renderer (WebGL and CSS3D).

The result looks like this, if some are interested in :

```
class css3d{
...

 render(){
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.canvas.camera);
 }
...
}
```

Have a good day and thanks for helping